# will an iOS app with multiple tracking SDKs attributed twice by Facebook?

Tags: facebook, sdk, tracking

If I deploy two tracking SDK in my iOS app, each one a Facebook MMP (e.g. Adjust + AppsFlyer), and then promote that app on Facebook "App Install Ads", how will an install be attributed: to both trackers? Just to one of them (which ever reports the install quicker to FB)?
thanks!

Comment: Facebook insights will only count / show installs as one irrespective of the tracking SDKs you have in your app.

Comment: So you mean there is an inherent race condition between multiple trackers because FB will only allow each install to be attributed once?

Comment: There's no race condition but if a MMP reports install to Facebook at around the same time, it will be deduplicated at our end.